# No response after broadcast receiver from service

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to send a string from service using broadcast receiver.
On reaching a location I want to send broadcast receiver but broadcast receiver is not able to send anything and nor I am getting any error in Logcat.Also I am not able to receive any error in both activity or service.

Following is my code in service class:-

```
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       inte.setAction("hello");
       inte.putExtra("StringFromService", genre);
       inte.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
      sendBroadcast(inte);
      }
```

Receiver inside another class:-

```
public class XYZ extends ListActivity {



public BroadcastReceiver myBR= new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String x= intent.getAction();
        Log.d("INside BroadcastReceiver", "inside" + x);

        if(x.equals("hello")){


            Toast.makeText(XYZ.this,"hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};







@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xyz);
 registerReceiver(myBR, new IntentFilter("hello"));
  }

}
```

Comment: and when/how you are starting the service ?

Comment: Have you register your BroadcastReciever?

Comment: Service is started onclick from button in another activity and yes broadcast receiver is registered.Check onCreate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger a broadcast, you have to register the receiver in the `onResume()` method like this:

```
registerReceiver(myBR, new IntentFilter("hello"));
```

and unregister the broadcast in the `onPause()` method

```
unregisterReceiver(myBR);
```